# TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined (react-native)

Tags: react-native

The code below gives a TypeError when I am trying to get `settings` property of `params`. How should I fix this issue?

This works:

```
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
console.log('from settings: ', params);
```

> from settings:
>   {settings: {…}} settings: {allDate: true, searchWord: "", todayNews: false, popularSorting: false, favoritesSorting: false}

But when I try to log the settings property of `params`, I get this error:

```
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state; 
console.log('from settings: ', params.settings);
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Comment: Hey try this `console.log(params.allDate)` this will print true

Comment: @RaajNadar undefined

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
render() {
 const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
           <Text>{params && params.settings 
? params.settings.searchWord 
: null}</Text>
           <Text>{params && params.settings 
? params.settings.allDate 
: null}</Text>
           <Text>{params && params.settings 
? params.settings.todayNews 
: null}</Text>
           <Text>{params && params.settings 
? params.settings.popularSorting 
: null}</Text>
           <Text>{params && params.settings 
? params.settings.favoritesSorting 
: null}</Text>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to pass and accept params

```
let id, name; //declare variables

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: 0,
            name: ''
        };

        let { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        id = params ? params.id : null; //set var if params.id exists else null
        name = params ? params.name : null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ id: id, name: name });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                { this.state.id }
                { this.state.name }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```